# Typescript: Specify the prototype as a value restricting it to the parent class

Tags: typescript

I need to pass a configuration object to a function, where the `is` field defines the prototype of the object being created, and the `options` field defines the properties of the first constructor argument, here for example:

```
{
  testClassA: {
    is: ClassA, // class ClassA { constructor(options: {foo: string}) }
    options: {       
      foo: 'bar'
    }
  },
  testClassB: {
    is: ClassB, // class ClassB extends ClassA { constructor(options: {bar: number}) }
    options: {
      bar: 1
    }
  }
}
```

This is how I want to implement lazy on-demand object creation. The problem is that the entry `U extends typeof ClassA` limits the valid values of the `is` property to the `ClassA` class only, and I want any classes extending it to be accepted.

Here is a link to the [sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDC5QILQN4ChrQGYHscC5oIAXAJwEsA7Acw2mB0pNIFdhidSAKHAB2PKMIhFLgJEyVagF8AlKjqZiAC3IQAdGOgBeaHwFDNeOtLSm0oSDHhWAQtACmAD2IPKAE2sIIyBZgZMZGwc3PqCTCIARmCkhJQsALaRDqRyfphELLwpXKJ4hADkBXImZmhoWCyU7OH0pA5grgA8AKqOLm6e0MQAntk4WHDeiAA00MjOrh4wKADaANbQVBIUNAC6ImqELdLQAGSoYUKEsEJB7JwACjFgCQ6upBCtAHyzAAxru9LP0FwBWORqCI6JYoA5hOMzPIUOZgPVGg5ciDvODgRluuDiDYkGj0UsIdifCNFBkjhF0njoAB6KkAPQA-CT0WJCtFSAUmdBTOjpMT0a4SITbLj0VshnY%20XiyRD0JTMDSGZzuRllaY5EA).

Any help would be appreciated.

UPD: Full example source code:

```
class ClassA {
  foo: string
  constructor(options: {foo: string}) {
    this.foo = options.foo
  }
}

class ClassB extends ClassA  {
  constructor(options: {bar: number}) {
    super({foo: ''})
  }
}

function create<U extends typeof ClassA, A extends {[k in string]: {is: U} & {options: ConstructorParameters<U>[0]} }> (config: {
  classes: A
}) {}

create({
  classes: {
    testClassA: {
      is: ClassA,
      options: {
        foo: 'bar'
      }
    },
    testClassB: {
      is: ClassB,
      options: {
        bar: 1
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Please include the plain text of your code here in addition to having it in the playground link.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WPxOeW) meet your needs?  You can't really have two parameters `U` and `A` and have inference work the way you want because there's only an inference site for `A` (`U` is not directly mentioned in the function parameter type at all), and even so, your `U extends typeof ClassA` constrains things in a way you don't want (you mention that it only allows `ClassA`; technically it will allow any subclass of `ClassA` whose static side is compatible, so the constructor would need to accept the same `options` argument). (more...)

Comment: If that code works for you I can write up an answer explaining it; otherwise please [edit] the example code to show unsatisfied use cases.

Comment: Yes, your code woks very well, please write an answer. And maybe you could recommend some resources explaining how to come to understand such complicated things in typescript. I'm very interested in the topic of deriving types from others, because I'm trying to write types for complex single-configuration objects.

Comment: Hmm, recommending resources... for me it was reading [basarat's TS Deep Dive](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript) and [the official TS handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/intro.html) and looking at the [TS issues in github](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues) and playing around with things.  It takes a while to build up an intuition about what the compiler is likely to do given a piece of code, and I don't know if I can explain how to get there.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the compiler to infer a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function's type parameters when you call the function, you should make sure there are good *inference sites* for these type parameters.  Let's look at a simple case of a good inference site:

```
declare function foo<T>(x: T): void;    
// good inference site: ^^^^
foo(new Date()); // function foo<Date>(x: Date): void
```

Here, the type of `x` is an inference site for `T`, since the value passed in for `x` when you call `foo()` can be used to infer `T`.  And it's a very good inference site: the type of `x` is `T`, and you want the compiler to infer `T`.  That means the compiler can just use the type of `x` as a candidate for `T` without having to do any more complicated inference tricks.  As you can see, in `foo(new Date())`, `T` is inferred as `Date`.

On the other end of the spectrum, you have this:

```
declare function bar<T>(x: string): void;
// no inference site:  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
bar("oops"); // function bar<unknown>(x: string): void
```

There is no inference site at all for `T`.  The call to `bar("oops")` doesn't give the compiler anything from which it can begin to infer `T`, and so the inference fails and falls back to an implicit [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) of `unknown`.

Most generic functions fall somewhere between these extremes:

```
declare function baz<T>(x: T | string): void;
// inference site:      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

baz(Math.random() < 0.5 ? 0 : "");
// function baz<number>(x: string | number): void

baz("hello");
// function baz<string>(x: string): void
```

Here the type of `x` is `T | string`, and given a value of type `T | string` you want the compiler to infer `T`.  In the first call, we passed in a value of the type `string | number`, and the compiler successfully infers `number` as the type for `T`.  So it does something like `Exclude<number | string, string>` to get `number`.  But in the second call, we passed in a value of type `string`, and the compiler infers `string` as the type for `T` instead of `Exclude<string, string>` or `never`.  Both inferences are "correct" in that they work: `string | string` is just `string`, but depending on the use case you may or may not like the inconsistency there.

One more example and then I'll stop:

```
declare function qux<T>(x: { [K in keyof T]: Array<T[K]> }): void;
// inference site ----> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
qux({ a: [1, 2, 3], b: ["x", "y"], c: [true, false] });
// function qux<{ a: number; b: string; c: boolean;}>(
//   x: { a: number[]; b: string[]; c: boolean[]; }
// ): void
```

Here we have what might look like a bad inference site: we need to infer `T` from a value of `{[K in keyof T]: Array<T[K]>}`, a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) where each property in `T` is wrapped in `Array<>`.  But amazingly the compiler succeeds!  You pass in a value of type `{a: number[], b: string[], c: boolean[]}` and the compiler undoes the mapping and produces a `T` of `{a: number, b: string, c: boolean}`.  This is known as [inference from mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#inference-from-mapped-types) (sorry there's no non-deprecated handbook link for that) and it only works because the mapped type is *homomorphic*, meaning we're mapping over properties of some object type (you can tell by the presence of `in keyof`).  And the compiler is quite good at doing this.

Anyway, if you find that inference doesn't happen the way you want, you might need to improve your inference sites by moving away from things it can't infer toward things it can.  This is somewhat hand-wavy advice, since it takes some experience to know what can and can't be inferred well.  If all else fails, make your type parameter the same as the type of the passed-in function argument and then compute the type you really wanted from it.

---

Let's look at your version of `create`'s call signature:

```
function create<
  U extends typeof ClassA,
  A extends { [k: string]: { is: U } & { options: ConstructorParameters<U>[0] } }
>(config: { classes: A }) { }
```

The first thing that immediately jumps out at me is that there is *no inference site* for `U`.  You might think that the constraint for `A` would be such an inference site, but that's not how it works.  See [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44711#issuecomment-867200067) on [microsoft/TypeScript#44711](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44711) for an authoritative statement that generic constraints are not inference sites in TypeScript.

That means inference for `U` will *always* fail and fallback to `typeof ClassA`, so your code is equivalent to

```
function create<
  A extends { [k: string]: { is: typeof ClassA } & { options: { foo: string } } }
>(config: { classes: A }) { }
```

The good news is that you have a very good inference site for `A`, but the bad news is that you don't want `A` to be constrained this way.  You want each property of `A` to possibly have its own one-arg subclass contructor of `ClassA`, which has a possibly different constructor argument from `{foo: string}`.  You *do* want to allow different contructor arguments, and you *don't* want to allow two different constructor types for the `is` and the `options` properties for any particular property of `A`.

So, instead of having both `is` and `options` inside the type parameter constraint, let's just have the type parameter be a straightforward mapping from key names to one-arg constructors of `ClassA` instances, and use a mapped type to represent the `is` and `options` stuff:

```
function create<A extends { [K in keyof A]: new (options: any) => ClassA }>(config: {
  classes: { [K in keyof A]: { is: A[K], options: ConstructorParameters<A[K]>[0] } }
}) { }
```

Here the constraint is recursive since it is of the form `A extends {[K in keyof A]: ...}`.  But all it means is that we do not care about the keys of `A`, and the compiler accepts it.  The constraint's property type is `new (options: any) => ClassA`, which is less specific than `typeof ClassA` since we don't care about the constructor argument type (except that the constructor doesn't need more than one argument) and we don't care about any `static` properties of the constructor either.

The mapped type for the `classes` property of `config` takes each property `A[K]` of `A`, which is some one-arg constructor of `ClassA`-or-a-subtype instances, and maps it to `{ is: A[K], options: ConstructorParameters<A[K]>[0] }`.  So the `is` property is just that constructor type, and the `options` property is that constructor's first (and only necessary) constructor argument.

---

So, does it work?

```
create({
  classes: {
    testClassA: {
      is: ClassA,
      options: {
        //^? (property) options: {foo: string;}
        foo: 'bar'
      }
    },
    testClassB: {
      is: ClassB,
      options: {
        //^? (property) options: {bar: number;}
        bar: 2
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Yes, looks good.  Let's make sure it gets mad if we do the wrong thing:

```
create({
  classes: {
    oops: {
      is: ClassB, options: { foo: "bar" } // error!
      // ------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~
      // Type '{ foo: string; }' is not assignable 
      // to type '{ bar: number; }'
    }
  }
})
```

Hooray!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtVJxwB4AVAPgAoAPALnhIEo6A3HLYAbgChFCLUQAd3gARKBhAUGDDvAD0cpGky58vYmImVao8SCbxW7Ll1CRYCFOmx54AI1iltdAM4YYWVAHMDRzlwcYCgAiQgAHF2CZeUUrFVtAojQAa1QcQVRneDcPb182YBMzaDgla1V7KAAvJ2o6EngAH2z3Tx8WAu4HKooAWXEACwA6GChUYBwAWyl4IngABiGAVngAfgX4OmCo7gUy+PxuolRkSbsQGCyctqb4E7OL-ONukIGQCAgcHa49uJtD6pEa7eK6tPIdYymcAlSzKf7wACOyCotR0AG94ABtADS8E88GSIAAnjhEPQALp0ACCMFGRNIOPJZHgAF8nv4kVQKBioHRMQBGAA08AATMKAMzk4V2PnBKjBYXBInBKXwMB89zIEDCxBQCAuEDk1kyH6xOEVTlEHl0e7nGCyGUtXJeWTq+yECAgMYcFmUU3wAPo+C8u6nO2Y8kO1xgrwR110Ower2oOOs-3skwmcwuFzwADC0BzVPgaK4AfU0edZbVeByyEwOCCODC-xcdAxFadNzZJerAYwAywLiG6ngAF54M3WyPCNWWVx51xs7mC1AcwAheAgKgScYrwsuYulgNgWuahtNluqNslyowG1hi7G3sBgMuZBhC7cgg4OgAcj-Y05wXTM-gqMA4D0AB5DwvCIasAFUtx3EA93gDAiU-Ul8wPKlBWrYtt13YBcwxTFkkrNpKVvIc6CQll4AAMlvKdrzoPMzxgesMEbAAFWAoEmEAJBgFwiAQshMXmI0GPnShT1QRAsC8ds1QPEAb2LHsMUXMDbAgr0JBg5SRXggNCJQtCyIortvGojFaPQzCQGw1ci1ZJiWKvWtVM7YEvA82SuHkvAlJU29lw06lnx0kw9PwAy9CICziNIrFcXxQkSTJKlqIEYQKFYnzg1QIkGHHZk3MPVkQsU5T22rSKbzIjL8Cy7DctUxyqUZYUitQG8OIG88eJgfjRiEkSxJ67EmSkmS020tMl0giRuUa9Tmr7dCNIwKqqQa19X0c-b8KOgN+q287XwUAA9VZtqOzs-0CP9HrTI6WTO18JDcKr10O86ToPddvqOy7Aeuu6HuugNAjoEV3vnT7gLZLNVskY81LXA0rtfcI8aO4GcdBydvIG3zCC2QJgg8vYLhgRsAEJ3r2ABaDnOa57nOeZAA-AXBaF1nFBIZz4D-Dsqdsl1WUAoc7hwDBgxzZTUCgOxPXgEX0JwJzPwljF4dDB57Tl7bkcW8quCAA)